# xmlstarlet Search Attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

XML Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profile>
<section name="Vision">
<key name="Name" value="BBBB"/>
<key name="Name_Remark" value="GGGG"/>
<key name="Position" value="30"/>
</section>
</profile>
```

How I can get value with xmlstarlet where name is "Position". Now is 30.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command line...

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/profile/section/key[@name='Position']/@value" -n input.xml
```

The `sel` command tells xmlstarlet to select.

The `-t` option tells xmlstarlet the options following `-t` are for templates.

The `-v` tells xmlstarlet to print the value of the XPath expression.

The `-n` tells xmlstarlet to print a new line. (Not completely necessary.)

All of this can be found by running `xmlstarlet sel --help` from the command line.

Comment: Thank for support. I have other one question: How I can get comma separated output in one line - for example 30,BBBB? Thanks

Comment: @Max-M - Please create another separate question. Feel free to add a link to it as a comment to this question.