# what is the xpath syntax to grab html tag elements?

Tags: html, xpath, syntax, command-line-interface, xmlstarlet

how do I print the title value for the below `html` file using `xmlstarlet`?

```
thufir@doge:~/.html$ 
thufir@doge:~/.html$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/html/header[@name='title']" -n hello.html 

thufir@doge:~/.html$ 
thufir@doge:~/.html$ cat hello.html 
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
thufir@doge:~/.html$
```

Grabbing `xml` might be a bit [different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44209350/262852) than html?  Assuming garden-variety `html` and not `xhtml`.

The reason I'm using `xmlstarlet` is specifically to use `xpath` syntax which seems rather alien.

Comment: "@" is for attributes, e.g. `<header name="title">`.

Comment: You can use `xmlstarlet fo --html` to reformat HTML into XML. http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s05.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

`"/html/header[@name='title']"`

you select an `header` element which has an attribute `name` with the value "title".

What you want is to grab a `title` element in an `header` element:

`//header/title`

or just use :

`//title`

which selects all title elements, regardless of its position in the tree.

Comment: ah, thanks for terminology.  clarifies.  `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/html/header[@name='title']" -n hello.html` not working for me.  (in this case, header is outside body)

Comment: thanks.  `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/html/header/title" -n hello.html` but forgot about the double slash, which also works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just cheat and use Chrome's Developer Tools.

Open the HTML in Chrome, open the Developer Tools, then in the Elements tab, right click and select Copy > Copy XPath.

`/html/body/header/title`

Comment: I see now. you mean:  `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/html/header/title" -n hello.html`.  thanks.  pardon, didn't understand what you meant at first.

Comment: Well, the XPath selector I gave is incorrect for the HTML in your question - Chrome coerced the invalid HTML into something that was valid, making the `<header>` a child of `<body>`.